# How to set Specific words font style quickly

Tags: c#, ms-word, add-in

Microsoft word didn't provide a spelling tool for my language and I want to do it with my self, every this is going fine and there is a small problem I need to solve.
In order to spell check for each words I need to get each words first. obviously if I used

```
  var doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
    int counts = doc.Words.Count;
    List<string> words=new List<string>;
    for (int i=0;i<counts;i++)
    {
        words.Add(doc.Words[i].Text.Trim());
    }
```

to get each words, it will run very slowly.
after that I write my own method to get each words, it runs good. after that I need to mark the wrong spelled words. I used

```
bool check = diccheck(word);
if (check == false)
{
    doc.Words[i].Font.Underline = Word.WdUnderline.wdUnderlineWavy;
    doc.Words[i].Font.UnderlineColor = Word.WdColor.wdColorRed;
}
```

and it is run very slow again. can any one help me show the way how to mark the wrong spelled words quickly?

Answer (score -1):

What do you think about a thread runs while you writes?

Are you trying to correct wrong words?

If i get it right, may be more usefull if you only checks the text that changed.

Comment: I need to check the file already written, each of them is big file. And yes, I need to correct wrong words, and each words need to check, because it hasn't checked before.

Comment: If I check the words I am typing, I don't need to it run quickly. But the problem is I need to check a big file already written and mark the wrong spelled words.

Comment: @iwethen So, how about you split the words by " " and run some threads (dont know how many would be), to verify the words? I guess it's the fatest way.